# AWS Boto3 - Add security group without removing existing security group

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-group

I have an use case to add security group to a bulk of ec2 instances in AWS, I chose python boto3 API to perform this action. However when using the below method, it removes the existing security group and then adds the new group.  I would just like to add new one to the existing SG.

```
ec2 = session.client('ec2')
ec2.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=xxxx, Groups= ['xxx']]
```

Any suggestions to do add SG without removing the existing security group?

```
ec2 = session.client('ec2')
ec2.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=xxxx, Groups= ['xxx']]
```

I understand its modify, but I don't see an option to just add SG.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the list of existing SGs, add the new one, and then set them all again to the instance.